# macOS Monterey: how to copy Login Keychain item to System Keychain

Tags: time-machine, keychain

I've just installed a Mac from scratch. On my previous Mac (with macOS X 10.x), I did copy the encryption password for my external Time Machine backup disks to the System Keychain so the machine could automatically backup without me being logged in.
It seems like I can't do this in Monterey any more - if I drag the item (with or without having the Option key depressed), I can't drop it onto the System Keychain in the left sidebar like I could in earlier macOS versions.
How can I copy the backup disk password to the System Keychain?

[image: Keychain item screenshot]

Comment: 1) On my Mac the encrypted volume passwords are, without me doing anything, in the system keychain as well as my login keychain. 2) Have you confirmed that TM does not backup when you are logged off?

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I re-checked, and while the password for my Time Capsule is in the System Keychain, the ones for my external, cable-bound backup disks are not.

I couldn't confirm yet whether TM does backup when I'm logged out, as the first backup to the Time Capsule is still running (takes a few days from experience). Should be finished by tomorrow afternoon…

Comment: I've logged out early this morning, and I've attached the external backup disk. So far (about 4 hours later) no backup on the external disk. So I assume that I can confirm that the OS can't mount the disk without me being logged in or the encryption key in the System Keychain.

Comment: Got it to work after all, it wasn't so hard. I unlocked the System Keychain, copied the respective keychain item from my Local Items keychain ⌘C, selected the System Keychain and pasted ⌘V, done :)